# Duda con useState de react: ¿Cómo puedo agregar objetos al array de otro objeto usando useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

En el código que expongo abajo, lo que quiero hacer es agrandar el array 'locationList' de mi objeto 'initialData' agregando un nuevo objeto 'locationData'. Como podrán ver, me estoy apoyando del useState, pero no encuentro la manera correcta de poder hacerlo correctamente. ¿Alguien me ayuda?

```javascript
const FullRoute = () => {

  const initialData = {
    locationList: [],
    otherList: []
  }

  const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);

  const addToLocationList = (locationData) => {
      setData({
        ...data,
        ['locationList']: locationData
      })

    }

    ...

}

export default FullRoute
```

Comment: ¿Por qué estás inicializando el `initialData` fuera del  `useState()`? ¿No sería más lógico hacerlo así `const [data, setData] = useState({locationList: [], otherList: []});`? Pienso que así te ahorrarías un paso innecesario.

Comment: Gracias por responder Desarrollos-Web-urquiza. Tienes razón, lo que pasa es que en el ejemplo real que estoy trabajando el objeto tiene más elementos, y se ve más prolijo separando la constante.

Comment: Gracias por responder Emeeus, pero no es correcto. Me larga el error de que locationData no es iterable.

Comment: locationData es un objeto del tipo { id: 0, longitude: -40000, latitude: 50000}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que crear una nueva lista añadiendo tu objeto en la lista.

```
const addToLocationList = (locationData) => {
  // se crea un nuevo array con el nuevo dato agregandolo y este luego se asigna al state
  const locationList = [...data.locationList, locationData]
  setData({
    ...data,
    locationList  // locationList: locationList es equivalente, en ES6 cuando la propiedad es la misma que la variable no hace falta especificarlo
  })

}
```

Comment: Idolo!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Me funcionó, pero es setData({ ...data.locationList, locationList})
Muchísimas gracias!!

Comment: si haces eso perderás los datos del `otherList`. Primero tienes que copiar el state que ya existe (`{...data}`) y luego asignar el nuevo valor a la propiedad `locationList`. Que es lo que te he puesto